# EC2 instance R Memory Usage

Tags: r, memory, memory-management, amazon-ec2

I am using RStudio on an AWS EC2 instance.
I created a for loop in R, to create dataframes based on certain conditions.
It's a long loop, and after quite sometime, my code stops with the error:

> 'Cannot allocate memory'

So I searched and created a variable to know what is the memory left on my instance at a given time with the below script:

```
memfree <- as.numeric(system("awk '/MemFree/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo", intern=TRUE))
cat('Free Memory: ', memfree, 'bytes\n')
```

The last number of free space that was shown before the crash is the following:

> Free Memory:  529336 bytes

And just after, I got this error:

> Error in system("awk '/MemFree/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo", intern =
>   TRUE) :    cannot popen 'awk '/MemFree/ {print $2}' /proc/meminfo',
>   probable reason 'Cannot allocate memory'

So now I am quite confused about the reason why the code stops because it seems there were still free memory in my EC2 instance.

Any help much appreciated !

Comment: Not sure about the memory-issue.. but a lot of for-loops can be replaced by much more efficient options (like `data.table` and/or `dplyr`-functions). Maybe it's time for optimisation?

Comment: I guess it would be optimized regarding the time of the execution of the script, but my main issue is more related to memory, and basically would like to understand how memory is handled in an EC2 environment.

Comment: what is the type of ec2 instance? Maybe you need a bigger instances. And you also need to figure out if you can optimize your processing to fit the memory that you instance has. See this https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ for a list of instances types and their specs.

Comment: But in my R environment I just have 3 small data frames as an output, so I feel like there is data stored somewhere that I do not see, would that be a possibility?